# Scroll in python Elasticsearch not working

Tags: python, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-query

I tried to scroll all documents with python when I query Elasticsearch so I can get over 10K results:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(ADDRESS, port=PORT)


result = es.search(
    index="INDEX",
    body=es_query,
    size=10000,
    scroll="3m")


scroll_id = result['_scroll_id']
scroll_size = result["hits"]["total"]
counter = 0
print('total items= ' + scroll_size)

while(scroll_size > 0):
    counter +=len(result['hits']['hits'])
   

    result = es.scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id, scroll="1s")
    scroll_id = result['_scroll_id']

    
print('found = ' +counter)
```

The problem is that sometimes the `counter` (the sum of the results at the end of the program) is smaller than `result["hits"]["total"]`. Why is that? Why does `scroll` not iterate over all the results?

```
ElasticSearch version : 5.6
lucence version :6.6
```

Comment: Try changing scroll_size like this ```scroll_size = result["hits"]["total"]["value"]```

Comment: @josephthomaa `scroll_size = result["hits"]["total"]["value"]` TypeError int object is not subscriptable    . But is think that the problem is not in `total items` that the right number , the problem is in the scroll

Comment: What ES version are you running?

Comment: @JoeSorocin 5.6

Comment: I tried your code and couldn't replicate your error. Can you provide some more detail? How large was the difference?

Comment: @JoeSorocin about 300K is the diffrence (1M instead of 1.3M)

Comment: @MicrosoctCprog Why you use an helpers that does all the dirty jobs for you? This is the scan helper https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan here a gist https://gist.github.com/davidski/39788b65ac2754c063bf

Comment: However the error seems to derive from increasing scroll_size inside the while loop. Here you can find a working example of scroll method in python: https://gist.github.com/drorata/146ce50807d16fd4a6aa

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, you're adding the initial `result["hits"]["total"]` to your `counter` in the first iteration of the `while` loop -- but you should be adding just the length of the **retrieved** hits:

```py
scroll_id = result['_scroll_id']
total = result["hits"]["total"]

print('total = %d' % total)

scroll_size = len(result["hits"]["hits"])  # this is the current 'page' size
counter = 0

while(scroll_size > 0):
    counter += scroll_size

    result = es.scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id, scroll="1s")
    scroll_id = result['_scroll_id']
    scroll_size = len(result['hits']['hits'])

print('counter = %d' % counter)
assert counter == total
```

As a matter of fact, you don't need to store the scroll size separately -- a more concise `while` loop would be:

```py
while len(result['hits']['hits']):
    counter += len(result['hits']['hits'])

    result = es.scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id, scroll="1s")
    scroll_id = result['_scroll_id']
```

Comment: I change my code and still I got into `found = `800K and in `total items` = 1.6M items

Answer (score 0):

Because the **1st Iteration is having 10K(generally default)** like here. You missed:
`result["hits"]["hits"] chunk`

you should try:

```
counter +=len(result['hits']['hits'])
```

[image]

Comment: I change my code and still I got into `found = `800K and in `total items` = 1.6M items